# How to set a timeout in COIN-OR Cbc via the command line tool?

Tags: c++, timeout, command-line-interface, coin-or-cbc

I'm using [COIN-OR Cbc](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc) via its `cbc` command line tool and need to abort some computations if they take too long.

I'm aware that I could write a controlling process around cbc to kill it after the timeout expires. I'm also aware that I could use cbc as C++ library. Both seem so be quite cumbersome, I'm looking for a simpler, direct solution.

Is this possible directly via the `cbc` command line tool?

If not, is there a simple way using cbc as C++ library? (read an `*.lp` file, apply timeout, create `*.soln` file)

Comment: I thought it would be clear from or "coin-or-cbc" tag. I adjusted the question to make clear which CBC tool / library I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use the `-sec` command-line option. The full command line would be:

```
cbc -sec 10 -import inputfile.lp -solve
```

This is equivalent to running an interactive session by typing only `cbc` on the command line, then entering the following commands:

```
sec 10
import inputfile.lp
solve
```